# how to access a component style in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div tag I want to render only if renderCard() style overflow is scroll. I have tried a renderCard().style.overflow which does not seem to target this

Edit: renderCard added

```
  const SearchCard = () => (
    <button class="invisible-button" onClick={onSearchCardClick}>
      //
    </button>
  );

  const AnswerCard = () => (
    <div className="results-set">
      //
    </div>
  );

  const renderCard = () => {
    if (card && card.answer) {
      return AnswerCard();
    } else if (card) {
      return SearchCard();
    }
    return null;
  };
```

```
    <React.Fragment>
      <div id="search-results">{renderCard()}</div>
      {renderFollowup ? null : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div id="search-footer">
            {
              (renderCard().style.overflow = "scroll" ? (
                <div className="scroll-button">
                  <a href="#bottomSection">
                    <img src="images/arrow_down.svg" alt="scroll to bottom" />
                  </a>
                </div>
              ) : null)
            }
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Attach a react ref to the element being rendered in `renderCard` to get a reference to the DOM node and check its style attribute. Can you update your question with your `renderCard` code?

Answer (score 4):

To do this you need a `ref` to the actual DOM element rendered by `renderCard()`.

`renderCard()` here returns a React element which doesn't have the style property or any other DOM properties on it - it's just a React representation of what the DOM element will eventually be once rendered - hence you need to get the actual DOM element via a `ref` where you'll have access to this and other properties.

Example code below using `useRef` to create the ref that will be attached to the element with the style you need to access. Note how `useEffect` is used to access the ref's value because it's only available after the first render when the DOM element is present.

```js
const Example = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    alert('overflow value is: ' + ref.current.style.overflow)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={{ overflow: 'scroll' }}>hello world</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: you should use a ref like this inside `renderCard()` to access the `style.overflow` of the relevant element

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the cards to be actual rendered components, pass the ref and attach to the elements

```
const SearchCard = ({ overflowRef }) => (
  <button ref={overflowRef} class="invisible-button" onClick={onSearchCardClick}>
    //
  </button>
);

const AnswerCard = ({ overflowRef }) => (
  <div ref={overflowRef} className="results-set">
    //
  </div>
);

const RenderCard = ({ overflowRef }) => {
  if (card && card.answer) {
    return <AnswerCard overflowRef={overflowRef} />;
  } else if (card) {
    return <SearchCard overflowRef={overflowRef} />;
  }
  return null;
};
```

In the component rendering them, create a ref using either `createRef` or `useRef` react hook if it is a functional component

```
const overflowRef = createRef();
```

or

```
const overflowRef = useRef();
```

Pass the ref to RenderCard, to be passed on

```
<RenderCard overflowRef={overflowRef} />
```

And then check the overflow value as such

```
overflowRef.current.style.overflow === "scroll"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the approach above you might want to refactor some of the HoC components and pass a function from parent to child that returns the ref of the element to be accessed also I am not sure of the scope of the   block of code where you are executing the ternary.

Perhaps a simpler hack is to rely on using a useState hook with vanilla DOM selectors and passing that into the  or even better, just add it to the stateless func component that wraps React.Fragment as a hook:

```
  const myComponent = () => {
      const [hasScrollOverflow, setHasScrollOverflow] = useState(false);

      React.useEffect(() => {
        const element = document.querySelector(".results-set");
        const elementStyle = element.style;

        if (elementStyle.getPropertyValue('overflow') === 'scroll') {
          setHasScrollOverflow(true);
        }

      }, [])
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div id="search-results">{renderCard()}</div>
          {renderFollowup ? null : (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div id="search-footer">
                {hasScrollOverflow ? (
                  <div className="scroll-button">
                    <a href="#bottomSection">
                      <img src="images/arrow_down.svg" alt="scroll to bottom" />
                    </a>
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
```